# How to evaluate $\iint_A \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy,$ where $A=[\frac{1}{a},a]\times[0,1]$

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals

I want to compute

$$\iint_A \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$ where $A:=\left[\frac{1}{a},a\right]\times[0,1]$.

I got that this is equal to $\int_{1/a} ^a \frac{1}{x}\arctan \Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big) \mathrm dx\ $ and I don't know what to do from here. Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: in this case i get $\int \frac{1}{u}arctanu \  du$

Comment: Hint: after you've integrated over $y$ make the change of variables $x\mapsto 1/x$, and add the resulting one-variable integral to the original one-variable integral.

Comment: A nice property you may find useful: for $s>0$, $$\arctan\frac{1}{s}=\frac\pi2-\arctan s$$

Comment: Another way:

Let $a\geq1$ and $$I(a)=\int_{\frac1a}^a \frac{\arctan(x)}x\,\mathrm dx.$$
Then, by the Fundamental Theorem of calculus (or Leibniz rule, if you want), $$I'(a)=\frac{\arctan(a)}{a}\cdot 1 - \frac{\arctan(\frac{1}{a})}{\frac{1}{a}} \cdot \left(-\frac{1}{a^2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2a}$$ So, since $I(1)=0$, we get $I(a)=\frac\pi2\ln(a)$

Answer (score 3):

Let's catch up with you:
$$\begin{align}
\iint\limits_A \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}dx\,dy &= \int\limits_{\frac{1}{a}}^a\int\limits_0^1\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}dy\,dx\\
&=\int\limits_{\frac{1}{a}}^a\int\limits_0^1\frac{1}{x^2(1 + (y/x)^2)}dy\,dx.
\end{align}$$
Taking $u = y/x, \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 1/x$ so the last integral becomes

$$\begin{align}
\int\limits_{\frac{1}{a}}^a\int\limits_0^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{1}{x(1 + u^2)}du\,dx
&= \int\limits_\frac{1}{a}^a\frac{1}{x}\arctan \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx \\
&=\int\limits_a^\frac{1}{a} -\frac{1}{u}\arctan u\,du \\
&= \int\limits_\frac{1}{a}^a \frac{1}{u}\arctan u\,du,
\end{align}$$
because $u = 1/x \implies du = -1/x^2\,dx = -u^2 \,dx \implies dx = du/u^2$ and $1/a \mapsto a, a \mapsto 1/a$. [Accordingly to WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%201%2Fx%20arctan%20x), the indefinite integral for your expression has no closed form (in terms of elementary functions), but Wolfram Mathematica tells us it has a closed form with those integration limits (kudos to [Semiclassical](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53063996#53063996))!

[image]

So we have to exploit our integration limits. Let $I =\int\limits_\frac{1}{a}^a\frac{1}{x}\arctan \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx$.  Since $\arctan x = \pi/2 - \arctan 1/x$,

$$\begin{align}
I &= \int\limits_\frac{1}{a}^a \frac{1}{u}\arctan u\,du,\\
&= \int\limits_\frac{1}{a}^a \frac{1}{u}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan \frac{1}{u}\right)\,du \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2}\left(\int\limits_\frac{1}{a}^a 1/u\,du\right) - I \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2}(\ln a - \ln(1/a)) - I \\
&= \pi \ln a - I.
\end{align}
$$

Therefore $I = \frac{\pi}{2}\ln a$, as desired.